# How to use asciinema offline?

Tags: command-line, tty, webserver, recording

How can I record and play [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) screen recordings in a LAN without internet connection?

The tool uploads the recordings per default to the asciinema website but I want to keep it local and run the player on a local webserver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass `asciinema rec` a file name as an argument, in which case it will simply save the recording to the local file and not try to upload it to the server. For example:

```
$ asciinema rec demo.cast
```

You can then play the recording locally (on the terminal) with:

```
$ asciinema play demo.cast
```

And finally upload it with:

```
$ asciinema upload demo.cast
```

See the [asciinema usage docs](https://asciinema.org/docs/usage) for more details on each of these.

You mentioned hosting the recording in your own server. In that case, you might want to look at [setting your own asciinema web app instance](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema-server/blob/develop/README.md#setting-up-your-own-asciinema-web-app-instance), which you need to run on your server in order to host screencasts you upload. That page has a link to the web app install guide (which by default runs in a Docker container.) Once you have that up and running, you can configure your local asciinema to upload to your server rather than the public one in asciinema.org.

Alternatively, you can simply host the asciinema player along with the `*.cast` files in a webserver and embed them directly into an HTML page, which sounds like you are looking for, as there is no `asciinema upload` step involved. See [these instructions](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema-player/blob/develop/README.md#use-the-player-in-your-html-page) for standalone usage of the asciinema-player app.

Comment: Do I need a asciinema server, or would it be sufficient to copy the javascript player and demo.cast on some webspace?

Comment: You describe the steps to upload on asciinema.org `$ asciinema upload demo.cast` and point to the docs for the local usage, which was asked. Could you update the answer so that it describes the local usage, please?

Comment: Ah you can use the standalone asciinema-player for what you want, there are instructions [here](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema-player/blob/develop/README.md#use-the-player-in-your-html-page). I'll update the answer with instructions.

Comment: Updated. @JonasStein please take another look.